Application not changing master on Sentinel + KeyDB pair dropdown
Description
I have 3 pairs of Sentinel + KeyDB working on separated machines. Sentinels connected between each other so they can observe dropdowns. Also, I have an application, which uses go-redis to connect to Sentinels. Connecton code:
client := redis.NewFailoverClient(&redis.FailoverOptions{
        MasterName:       "master",
        SentinelAddrs:    []string{"addr1:26379","addr2:26379","addr3:26379"},
        SentinelPassword: "pass",
        Password:         "pass",
    })


In case when KeyDB master gets down, appication understands it and make a connection to new master logging this message:
sentinel: new master="master" addr="addr2:6379"


In case when observed Sentinel gets down, appication understands it and make a connection to new Sentinel logging this message:
redis: discarding bad PubSub connection: EOF

Problem
I've got a case, when a pair Sentinel + KeyDB (addr1:26379), observed by an application, drops down together. At the moment, application logs this:
redis: discarding bad PubSub connection: EOF

But then, when I try to make a request via client, I get an error like this:
dial tcp addr1:26379: i/o timeout

For me it seems like by some reason Failover Client not switching Sentinels (other 2 pairs of Sentinel + KeyDB continue working with new master), when an observed pair falls down.
Question
What did I miss, so the propably common case makes this behavior? Is it my fault or I should open an issue  in go-redis or key-db?
I've tried client different client options like timeouts, but nothing force client to change Sentinel address.
I expect client to understand that Sentinel is down and switch to another instance and get new master.
